# Replace string in multiple files using find and sed

Tags: sed, find, recursive, replace

So I've arrived at the conclusion that for recursively replacing all instances of a string in directory (only for .java extensions files) I need to use

```
find . -type f -name "*.java" -exec sed -i 's/original/result/g' {} +
```

However what do I do if the string I am trying to replace contains `/`?

For example I want to replace string `/*Comment*/` with a couple normal words, what delimiters should I use, so that sed works properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the slash, writing `\/`
You could also do:

```
perl -pi -e 's!original!result!g' *java
```

using `!` as a delimiter instead of `/`. This is a bit shorter than using find & sed.

Comment: but not entirely equivalent of `find + sed/awk/perl` combo as this one works only for files in current directory while `find` will work recursively

Answer (score 5):

You can use any delimiter using `sed` too (not only with `perl` as @vesa-karjalainen suggested), e.g.

```
find . -type f -name "*.java" -exec sed -i 's:original:result:g' {} +
```